# how to play youtube videos in half and full screen (iOS 6,7)

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I have already posted two questions
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498721/integration-of-youtube-in-my-ios-app) [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508816/how-to-show-youtube-videos-in-webview-of-restricted-heightwidth-ios)

last week, but no answer worked. I am working on an app(I have completed the UI), 
I have to show the youtube videos in the app, just like the youtube app. that is to show youtube videos in the full mode and in half screen too.

Some Body told me to use **MPMoviePlayerViewController** , but the problem with this player is, that it takes the url of videos like "www.xyz.com/videos.mov". It doesn't play youtube videos. I went to [Youtube Developer](https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/en-GB/) site. There is lot of information, but all that is for some scripting(javascript using iframe) language, that I don't understand.

Its been a week, and am stuck with this youtube API(I tried to read each and every thing on youtube developer blog, but most of the stuff is related to javascript, which I don't know).

There are few codes available over stackoverflow and Github, which are very old, and are not working now.

If any body know anything then please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to play YouTube videos with `MPMoviePlayerController` using [LBYouTubeView Library](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView).

Which is a good and upto date library. Basically it extract "www.xyz.com/videos.mov" kind of URL from YouTube and plays in a `MPMoviePlayerController`. You can also set the quality of the video (low,medium,high) etc. This library comes with a sample project you can test.

Comment: It works perfectly and I currently have an app in appstore developed using this library.

Comment: I found "XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController" using " LBYouTubeView Library" as you mentioned. I am able to show youtube video in half screen, but in half screen control disappears after 4 seconds. Now, am un able to customize "mpmovieplayerviewcontroller"

 If you can help me related to "mpmovieplayerviewcontroller" Please help

Comment: Got it, I was adding the "XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController" player over an ImageView, which didn't let me allow to touch the default buttons of the player. Now I have added it over UIVIEW, which is a container class, and now it is working, Thanks

Comment: Is this library against youtube terms ?